# Installation stuck on first page while installing Joomla 3.x with free template built-in

Tags: installation

I've found a free template compatible with both Joomla 2.5 and Joomla 3.X at [this link](http://www.optimumtheme.com/themes/bedava-theme.html#download).

In the page there is a quickstart archive that contains the Joomla setup and the template files built-in to easily get a website similar to the demo showed. I copied all the files in that archive in my web space for a new installation (hosting Linux, MySQL database, PHP version 5.3.28). The installation stucks on the first page. When I click "Next" after having filled the form (site name, admin credentials, etc) the setup doesn't go to the following page (the database one) and is locked in a infinite loading. Is this a known incompatibility with my PHP version and that Joomla package? I don't get this problem with a clean installation of the latest Joomla release followed by the installation of the standalone template, but I'd like to use the quickstart since my web page will be exactly the same as the demo.

What's the easiest wat to get a web page similar to the demo? Is it possible to move some folders from the quickstart archive to the latest joomla setup to achieve the same result?

It's the second time I use this CMS so I'm absolutely not expert (this is the reason why I tried to find a ready-to-go template). Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, you PHP version is fine. This is an issue you should contact the developer of the template about as they may have made a mistake with the installation package

Answer (score 1):

As Lodder says there is probably an issue with the template installation package, I will try install it myself tomorrow if I get a chance and let you know the results.

Alternatively you could install a different template? There are a number of similar (free) templates available which are also responsive and come with a quick start package. Have a look at [this template](http://www.joomlart.com/demo/#purity_iii), it's also T3 framework, I personally use it and think it's excellent. This should help you out if you need to find a 'ready-to-go template' as you say.

Comment: Thanks for your answer: that template is very good! Have you tried to install Bedava?

Comment: Yes it works fine for me. Have you tried installing it locally on your computer via XAMPP? This will rule out any issues with your remote hosting (although I doubt that will be the case). There is a helpful guide here http://www.joomlart.com/documentation/other/quickstart-installation

Comment: I tried to install the template on my computer with no success: this is what I've done. I downloaded XAMPP from apachefriends (Windows, v. 1.8.3 - PHP 5.5.11); installed it ad admin; run the Control Panel as admin; correctly started Apache and MySQL; deleted the content of the "htdocs" folder; extracted the content of the quickstart archive to "htdocs". When I try to connect to localhost with any of my browser (Firefox, Chrome, Opera - latest version) the first Joomla installation page comes up, but the installation stucks as always on the first step: I can't reach the database page...

Comment: I have just completely removed it and re-installed once more within 5 mins with no problems. All working. Your steps sound correct. Download XAMPP, start Apache & MySQL. Create a folder in your htdocs called 'bedava'. Extract the contants of the Bedava quickstart to your newly created 'bedava' htdocs folder. Go to your browser & type localhost/phpmyadmin Create a new database called bedava, create a new user called bedava, give the user a password.Now go to localhost/Bedava and you will see the joomla installer page, enter details, next > enter database & user details you just created. Done.

Comment: Incredible: I've followed your guide step by step but nothing changes. I see the installer page, I write my details and I press next, but the installation stucks. I'll try with another PC. Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you say it stucks, any error messages? What page does it stop at? Latest version of xampp? That is strange.

Comment: No error message. Latest version on xampp. The page is locked with a blue progress bar in the center of the page (endless loading).

Comment: Have you tried it on a different computer as suggested, and/or different browser? There are three steps (configuration, database, overview), and you get stuck at step 1 if I am correct? I can just confirm that the installation and quick start package worked for me on Win 7, XAMPP 3.1, Chrome.

Comment: Tried on another PC. Same error. Blue endless progress bar. Version 3.X seems to be impossibile to use for me. I'd use 2.X. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have problems with php scripts acceleration (your hosting provider).
We've found that same problem with EAccelerator module.
Problem appears only with installation Joomla 3.x

Tell your hosting admin to change modules.
There's more about that at http://www.i-host.pl/blog,joomla_34_eaccelerator_crash.html